# how to do localization for UIDatepicker in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uidatepicker

I am able to do localization of my datepicker by adding following line in my code

datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_US")

datePicker.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_US")

But still the time label is showing in english language can someone explain how i can change this to french aswell. TIA

[current condition of UIDatepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoiWV.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your language in locakizations file
as this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZbEa.png)

this image after i try this in this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myRTl.png)

Comment: datePicker has no property dateFormatter can you show me some code sample

Comment: I'm editing my answer, I hope this answer helps you ,try to connect with me if you need more explanation

Comment: If I change the language of my iphone then i am also getting this but I am trying to do localization from my app, so just want to know have you changed the language of iphone from settings ?

Comment: I try it in two cases if the iPhone setting is french and if the project scheme in french and it work correctly in two cases